# How to read asynchronous file I/O on Linux linking with Oracle Client 12c libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, oracle12c

The following code works just fine when linking with Oracle client 11g but if I compile the same linking with Oracle 12c libraries I receive the error EINVAL Invalid argument - errno 22.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <aio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE_TO_READ = 100;

int main()
{
    // open the file
    int file = open("blah.txt", O_RDONLY, 0);

    if (file == -1)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // create the buffer
    char* buffer = new char[SIZE_TO_READ];

    // create the control block structure
    aiocb cb;

    memset(&cb, 0, sizeof(aiocb));
    cb.aio_nbytes = SIZE_TO_READ;
    cb.aio_fildes = file;
    cb.aio_offset = 0;
    cb.aio_buf = buffer;

    // read!
    if (aio_read(&cb) == -1)
    {
        cout << "Unable to create request!" << endl;
        close(file);
    }

    cout << "Request enqueued!" << endl;

    // wait until the request has finished
    while(aio_error(&cb) == EINPROGRESS)
    {
        cout << "Working..." << endl;
    }

    // success?
    int numBytes = aio_return(&cb);

    if (numBytes != -1)
        cout << "Success!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Error!" << endl;

    // now clean up
    delete[] buffer;
    close(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Then to compile I first set the env variables

```
export ICLIBHOME=/u01/oracle/product/Linux/2.6/x86_64/clients/12.1.0.2/64bit/client/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ICLIBHOME}
```

Afterwards I compile and execute my compiled file but I get the error

```
g++ myaio.cpp -o myaio -lrt -L${ICLIBHOME} -lclntsh
./myaio
Unable to create request 22
```

Comment: Where does the '`Invalid argument - errno 22`' get generated in that code?  It isn't obvious which line(s) produces that message.

Comment: The error happens in the following lines:

    if (aio_read(&cb) == -1)
    {
        cout << "Unable to create request!" << endl;
        close(file);
    }

Comment: The output you show doesn't say 'Unable to create request!'; it says 'Invalid argument - errno 22'.  So, the code you show is not the code you execute, which makes it hard for us to guess what the problem actually is.  Please sort things out so at least the code and the error message are self-evidently self-consistent.  It isn't clear why that code is linked with the Oracle libraries; it looks like regular POSIX calls throughout.  Why is that necessary? Are you building this on the same machine with the two different versions of Oracle, or on two different machines?

Comment: I just modified the error according to my code. I had put down the previous error because that is the actual error after investigation. 
I have two different versions of oracle on the same machine, and I am only changing the ICLIBHOME variable. So when I point to Oracle 11g it work correctly but with Oracle 12c it gives me the error.

Comment: What happens if you don't link with the Oracle libraries at all?  The sample code doesn't seem to need them.

Comment: If I don't link with Oracle libraries it works fine, but this code is going to be modified and used to connect to the Database so first we need to make sure that it works with oracle libraries.

Comment: That is extremely weird.  You may need to take a look at the Oracle libraries and see whether they define dummy `aio_*()` functions that fail, or something outlandish like that.  Adding an 'unused' library to the linking process should not affect the behaviour of the program.  You'll probably need to use `nm` with appropriate options to find out what symbols are defined in the Oracle library.  If you do find something in the 12c library, check whether it is in the 11g library too.  If not, then you know what's going on — but not why. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ If (and I still consider it extremely improbable) they're defined in the Oracle 12c library and not the 11g library, then presumably, Oracle considers that its library cannot be used safely by programs that use the AIO functions. However, there should be discussion of such issues somewhere in the release notes, especially as it would be a change from 11c. I re-emphasize, I consider this to be a far-fetched, improbable source of the trouble.  But there's something in the Oracle 12c library that was not in 11g that causes trouble. Careful analysis of `nm` output may show what.